# C++11 discarding numbers in a PRNG sequence

Tags: c++, c++11, random

I am trying to use the function [`discard`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/mt19937/) to skip numbers in a sequence of random numbers. Here is my try:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  unsigned seed = 1;
  uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,10);
  mt19937 gen (seed);
  cout << dis(gen) << endl;
  //gen.discard(1); // supposed to be the same of `dis(gen)`?
  cout << dis(gen) << endl;
  cout << dis(gen) << endl;
}
```

The output of this code is

```
9.97185
9.32557
1.28124
```

If I uncomment the line with `gen.discard(1)` I get

```
9.97185
0.00114381
3.02333
```

but I was expecting that the first two numbers are `9.97185` and `1.28124`, since the number `9.32557` would be skipped.

**Q**: How to use `discard` properly or, is there an alternative solution with the same effect I want? I could simply use `dis(gen)`, but is there another way?

Comment: Why do you want to skip values?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The distribution can call the generator more than once when generating the next result, so to get the desired output you need to advance the state of the generator by a matching number of calls. As a quick test, if we rig our own generator to count the number of calls

```
struct my_mt19937 : mt19937
{
    using mt19937::mt19937;
    unsigned called = 0;

    mt19937::result_type operator()()
    {
        ++called;
        return mt19937::operator()();
    }

    unsigned invocations()
    { 
        auto result = called;
        called = 0;
        return result;
    }
};
```

And then use that instead

```
unsigned seed = 1;
uniform_real_distribution<> dis(0,10);
my_mt19937 gen (seed);

cout << dis(gen) << endl;
cout << gen.invocations() << endl;

cout << dis(gen) << endl;
cout << gen.invocations() << endl;

cout << dis(gen) << endl;
cout << gen.invocations() << endl;
```

This produces the [following result on gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e4ea0784b4b2b96)

```
9.97185
2
9.32557
2
1.28124
2
```

So the generator is being called twice to produce each result. Now, if we modify your example to call `gen.discard(2);`, it produces the [result you expect](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e45dff0221a711d8).

```
9.97185
1.28124
9.99041
```

I don't know of a portable way to determine the number of times a distribution will invoke the generator, so your best bet to discard an intermediate result is to probably call `dis(gen);` and ignore that result.

Comment: @montefuscolo Calling twice is because mt19937 uses 32 bit integers, while uniform_real_distribution uses (by default) doubles (64 bits).  So two calls to the generator are required for each retrieved random number, and 2 discards are required from the generator to keep things in order.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm That seems to be the case with libstdc++, but can you show me anything in the standard that prevents a distribution implementation from invoking the generator an extra time just for the heck of it? From the searching I did, only `generate_canonical` has specific requirements on the number of generator invocations, but other distributions are implementation defined.

Comment: I don't see anything to that limits the number of times an engine can call a generator, provided that it is consistent in the number of calls used to generate a number (the "amortized constant number of invocations of g").  The implication with `generate_canonical` is that the number of calls will be minimal but I do not see this explicitly stated anywhere.  As an additional datapoint, the <random> header in VS2015 uses `generate_canonical` extensively, although this does not appear to be the case for previous VS versions.